# How can you compute a simplified Groebner basis in GAP?

Tags: symbolic-math, groebner-basis, gap-system

I tried to use Buchberger's Algorithm (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchberger%27s_Algorithm) or [this](http://www.geocities.com/famancin/buchberger.html)) to compute a Groebner basis for an ideal in rational field. Here is my GAP script:

```gap
F := Rationals;
R := PolynomialRing( F, [ "x", "y", "z" ]);
x := IndeterminatesOfPolynomialRing(R)[1];
y := IndeterminatesOfPolynomialRing(R)[2];
z := IndeterminatesOfPolynomialRing(R)[3];
I := Ideal (R, [x^2+2*x*y^2, x*y + 2*y^3 - 1]);
ord := MonomialLexOrdering(x,y,z);

GroebnerBasis( I, ord );
```

but the result is always this:

```gap
[ 2*x*y^2+x^2, 2*y^3+x*y-1, -x, -4*y^4+2*y, 2*y^3-1 ]
```

Obviously, the fourth can be completely divided by the last basis, the first and second can be completely divided by the third basis. The expected result should be like this:

```gap
 [ -x, 2*y^3-1 ]
```

So my question is how to get the simplified Groebner basis in GAP?

Answer (score 4):

Try the [ReducedGroebnerBasis](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap66.html#X7DEF286384967C9E) command:

```gap
gap> ReducedGroebnerBasis(I, ord);
[ y^3-1/2, x ]
```